# play framework--- HTML submit button controller code

Tags: html, model-view-controller, intellij-idea, playframework

what more code should i use for play framework in intellij... I just need to display a welcome to homepage body(LoginSuccess.scala.html) page after clicking submit button

I want to display a message like welcome to HomePage

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
welcome to homepage
</body>
</html>
```

by using this code after clicking submit button.. should i write any controller code for it. if so please answer here

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
Username<input type="text" name = "uname">
password<input type="password" name="pword"
<input type="submit" value ="submit"
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To redirect to the home page you need a controller that renders it.

For instance if I have HomeController and a function inside it that does something like:

```
public Result welcome() {
        return ok(views.html.index.render());
    }
```

Then you would have to set up your routes file to do something like

```
GET     /                      controllers.HomeController.welcome()
```

Once that is done then you can put do something like this on your button code:

```
<input onclick="window.location.href='@routes.HomeController.welcome()'"></input>
```

I would suggest using a javascript function to redirect to a page if you are going to be using an input html object but if you want you can also do something like this

```
<a href="@routes.HomeController.welcome()">
     <div class="my-button">Button</div>
</a>
```

Then you can style the class my-button to make it look like a button.

I hope that answers your question.

Comment: Got this error in localhost:9000 after run command in sbt

ProvisionException: Unable to provision, see the following errors:

1) Error injecting constructor, Configuration error: Configuration error[Cannot load class filters.ExampleFilter]
  at play.api.http.EnabledFilters.<init>(HttpFilters.scala:68)

Comment: After doing what? Looks like you have added some sort of a Filters class to your application.

Comment: i have done nothing i just implemented your code but when i run from sbt i got that error

Comment: I hope you changed the names from my example to your class names, have you done so ?

Comment: yes i have two hmtl pages with Login.scala.html and Loginsuccess.scala.htm

and controller with HomeController and routes with     GET     /                      controllers.HomeController.welcome()

home controller with this code

public class HomeController extends Controller {


    public Result welcome() {
        return ok(views.html.LoginSuccess.render());
    }

}

Comment: I'm going by the assumption that you are using play 2.6, correct ?

Comment: Did you try using this instead of your button ?

<a href="@routes.HomeController.welcome()">
     <div class="my-button">Button</div>
</a>

That works for me!